# Calculate the possible permutations given a length and possible characters

Tags: python, combinations, permutation

I'm trying to calculate the number of permutations possible given a set of characters for example : `'a','b'` and a length for example `2`.

```
from itertools import product
mystr = 'ABC'
prodlen = 3
products = list(product(mystr,repeat=prodlen))
print(products)
```

but that's printing:

```
[('A', 'A', 'A'), ('A', 'A', 'B'), ('A', 'A', 'C'), ('A', 'B', 'A'), ('A', 'B', 'B'), ('A', 'B', 'C'), ('A', 'C', 'A'), ('A', 'C', 'B'), ('A', 'C', 'C'), ('B', 'A', 'A'), ('B', 'A', 'B'), ('B', 'A', 'C'), ('B', 'B', 'A'), ('B', 'B', 'B'), ('B', 'B', 'C'), ('B', 'C', 'A'), ('B', 'C', 'B'), ('B', 'C', 'C'), ('C', 'A', 'A'), ('C', 'A', 'B'), ('C', 'A', 'C'), ('C', 'B', 'A'), ('C', 'B', 'B'), ('C', 'B', 'C'), ('C', 'C', 'A'), ('C', 'C', 'B'), ('C', 'C', 'C')]
```

instead what I need is: `A, B, AA, BB, AB, BA` and I need the total number of those permutations. The number should go as high as the example below:

```
17  131072
16  65536
15  32768
14  16384
13  8192
12  4096
11  2048
10  1024    
9   512
8   256
7   128
6   64
5   32
4   16
3   8
2   4
1   2
Total = 262142
```

Comment: See [this](http://www.mathwords.com/p/permutation_formula.htm)

Comment: Looks like `2^n`

Comment: Also, what happens when `mystr='AABC'`? Do you count the As twice or only once?

Comment: It would be only once and I need the number because it will be part of a condition in my algorithm to limit the amount of iterations

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If what you want is to determine how many ways k characters can be chosen from a set of n characters with replacement, then for each of k characters you have n choices. This amounts to `n^k`, because you have n options for each of k choices. If you want the total number of such combinations with *at most* k characters, you want something like this:

```
my_string = 'ab'
n = len(set(my_string))
k = 17
p = sum([n**(i+1) for i in range(k)])  # 262143
```

Comment: but I need it to grow depending on the characters and the length I'm providing, for example: characters `abcde` and length `5` or `ab` and length `17` which should give me `131072`

Comment: If `ab` length 17 gives you 131072, I can only imagine that what you're talking about isn't actually permutations. Does this also mean that `abcde` length 5 should give you 3125?

Comment: No `abcde` should give me `3905` since you can create not only the initial combinations of length 5 but also the other length `4,3,2,1`

Comment: So you want the number of all combinations from that set of characters with a length of _at most_ 5? and in that case why does 17 give you 131072? shouldn't it give you a way higher number?

Comment: Yes my bad it should be `262142`

Comment: Edited to exclude duplicate characters, per your recent comment on the question

Comment: what's the difference between `len(s)` and `len(set(my_string))` both are giving me `262142` as the total for `ab` and `17`

Comment: @gabb `len('aaa')` is 3, `len(set('aaa'))` is 1 because `set('aaa')` is `{'a'}`. It just creates a set from the characters, which by definition does not include duplicates.

Answer (score 1):

Seems like you want

```
mystr='AB'
u=len(set(mystr))
r = 17
s={}
for i in range(1,r+1):
    s[i] = u**i

{1: 2,
 2: 4,
 3: 8,
 4: 16,
 5: 32,
 6: 64,
 7: 128,
 8: 256,
 9: 512,
 10: 1024,
 11: 2048,
 12: 4096,
 13: 8192,
 14: 16384,
 15: 32768,
 16: 65536,
 17: 131072}
```

Comment: Yes this is what I need, now I guess I can just add a counter and sum it all to get the total?

Comment: just `sum(s.values())`